# Mod_mono and apache on mac os x 10.6

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, macos, mono

I've installed mod_mon 2.10 and xsp 2.10 from sources(by instructions in tarballs). But I always have 'Internal Server Error' when I try to open ASP page.
I've looked /var/log/apache2/error_log and last lines were:

```
    mod_mono and xsp have different versions.
[Tue Mar 08 14:56:31 2011] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
[Tue Mar 08 14:56:31 2011] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1
[Tue Mar 08 14:56:31 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.34] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/favicon.ico
```

my mod_mono and xsp have different versions... Really:

```
    MacBook-Pro-Siarhei-Fedartsou:bin siarheifedartsou$ xsp --versionxsp.exe 1.1.16.1
(c) (c) 2002-2005 Novell, Inc.
Minimalistic web server for testing System.Web
```

I think that 1.1.16.1 version of xsp was installed when I installed mono. I think that I can remove this version and than 2.10 version of xsp will work. But I don't know how to remove old version. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

did you add mod_mono.so to your httpd.conf file?  the apache config was the hard part for me, especially since the Mono distribution doesn't seem to come with the necessary apache library.  I found compiled versions of the mod_mono.so file here:

http://www.markdeepwell.com/2010/07/mod_mono-so-library-os-x/

see my other stackoverflow post on this topic for more config info.

[How do I host multiple MVC3 sites on a single virtual host running Apache2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281182/mod-mono-config-for-multiple-applications-on-a-single-virtual-host)